# Deciphering Node.js App Logs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running a Kube cluster on AWS and things have been going smooth. For some reason or another, our Node app keeps crashing and we get the following repeating logs from our instances....

I have been searching for answers but have come up short and am fairly new to Node... can someone guide me in the right way to debugging this?

Thank you!!

```
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test] buffer.js:500 
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test] throw new Error('"toString()" failed'); 
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test] ^ 
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test]  
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test] Error: "toString()" failed 
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test] at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:500:11) 
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test] at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:552:33) 
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test] at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:549:20) 
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test] at Module.load (module.js:458:32) 
    [api-test-1214783129-8pg3b api-test] at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12) 


[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] /code/src/core:1 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ELF 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] ^ 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Module._compile (module.js:513:28) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Module.load (module.js:458:32) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Function.cls_wrapMethod [as _load] (/code/src/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:257:38) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Module.require (module.js:468:17) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at require (internal/module.js:20:19) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Object.<anonymous> (/code/src/jsonwebtoken.js:10:12) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Module._compile (module.js:541:32) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Module.load (module.js:458:32) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] at Function.cls_wrapMethod [as _load] (/code/src/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:257:38) 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1 
[api-test-1214783129-ii8f3 api-test] error: Script restart attempt #86
```

Comment: on what version of node and npm is your app running ?

Comment: It looks like an issue with the newrelic instrumentation

Comment: We are using Node Version: v6.3.1 and NPM version 3.10.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is saying that the source code of the module failed to be read. Specifically, the bytes representation (`Buffer`) could not be converted to a string.

This happens if your code is not saved as plain UTF-8.

In your case, that's because when node executes `require('./core');`, it looks for a file `core`, but finds ... a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump). To avoid this problem, do any or a combination of the following:

- replace `require('./core');` in jsonwebtoken.js with `require('./core.js');`
- Rename the file `core.js` and the corresponding require to, say, `ourcore.js` and `require('./ourcore');`
- Remove or rename the file `/code/src/core`. This workaround is only temporary though.
- [Disable core dumping](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Core_dump#Disabling_automatic_core_dumps) or fix the (unrelated) application that's crashing.

---

<sup>For a similar error message, other explanations could be:</sup>

<sup>Older node versions (although not node v6.3.1) even stumbled over the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). Open your file in a hex editor and look at the start. Are all of those characters ASCII?</sup>

<sup>You can use the hex editor to remove a BOM - simply remove the leading non-ASCII characters. Alternatively, open the file in a programming text editor - for instance sublime, vscode, kate, notepad2, etc. - and save it as UTF-8 without BOM.</sup>

Comment: Hi, I am currently using ATOM and it says its using UTF-8 encoding. Any thoughts?

Comment: Great, so the problem is almost certainly a BOM at the start. Unfortunately, I don't think Atom can natively toggle to save with/without BOM. You could copy everything but the first character of the file into a new one, type the first character, and save it with Atom under the old name. Alternatively, remove the BOM with a hex editor. If this is not successful, please upload the file or its hexdump somewhere so we can have a look.

Comment: So our project is quite large with many files. Would you have any suggestions on how to find the file that contains the BOM or would all files?

Comment: You can easily remove BOMs from all files, [see this question on our sister site for some one-liners](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381230/5303). Call that on every file in your repository, with a tool like `find`.